# How to add json data to specific index in another json using angularjs

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

My response json is from the API is as follows:

```
{
    "columnHeaders": [
        {
            "columnName": "id",
            "columnType": "bigint",
            "columnLength": 0,
            "columnDisplayType": "INTEGER",
            "isColumnNullable": false,
            "isColumnPrimaryKey": true,
            "columnValues": [],
            "visibilityCriteria": []
        },
        {
            "columnName": "client_id",
            "columnType": "bigint",
            "columnLength": 0,
            "columnDisplayType": "INTEGER",
            "isColumnNullable": false,
            "isColumnPrimaryKey": false,
            "columnValues": [],
            "visibilityCriteria": []
        },

        {
            "columnName": "countries",
            "columnType": "int",
            "columnLength": 0,
            "columnDisplayType": "CODELOOKUP",
            "isColumnNullable": false,
            "isColumnPrimaryKey": false,
            "displayName": "null",
            "dependsOn": 0,
            "orderPosition": 0,
            "visible": false,
            "mandatoryIfVisible": false,
            "columnValues": [
                {
                    "id": 19,
                    "value": "India",
                    "score": 0,
                    "parentId": 0
                },
                {
                    "id": 20,
                    "value": "USA",
                    "score": 0,
                    "parentId": 0
                }
            ],

            "columnCode": "countries",
            "visibilityCriteria": []
        }
    }
]
```

now i want to add following json to my existing json data.

```
"columnValuesLookup": [
                {
                    "id": 19,
                    "value": "English",
                    "score": 0,
                    "parentId": 0
                },
                {
                    "id": 20,
                    "value": "SA",
                    "score": 0,
                    "parentId": 0
                }
            ],
```

how do i add json data to a specific index in existing json object so that my final json looks like

```
{
    "columnHeaders": [
        {
            "columnName": "id",
            "columnType": "bigint",
            "columnLength": 0,
            "columnDisplayType": "INTEGER",
            "isColumnNullable": false,
            "isColumnPrimaryKey": true,
            "columnValues": [],
            "visibilityCriteria": []
        },
        {
            "columnName": "client_id",
            "columnType": "bigint",
            "columnLength": 0,
            "columnDisplayType": "INTEGER",
            "isColumnNullable": false,
            "isColumnPrimaryKey": false,
            "columnValues": [],
            "visibilityCriteria": []
        },

        {
            "columnName": "countries",
            "columnType": "int",
            "columnLength": 0,
            "columnDisplayType": "CODELOOKUP",
            "isColumnNullable": false,
            "isColumnPrimaryKey": false,
            "displayName": "null",
            "dependsOn": 0,
            "orderPosition": 0,
            "visible": false,
            "mandatoryIfVisible": false,
            "columnValues": [
                {
                    "id": 19,
                    "value": "India",
                    "score": 0,
                    "parentId": 0
                },
                {
                    "id": 20,
                    "value": "USA",
                    "score": 0,
                    "parentId": 0
                }
            ],
            "columnValuesLookup": [
                {
                    "id": 19,
                    "value": "English",
                    "score": 0,
                    "parentId": 0
                },
                {
                    "id": 20,
                    "value": "SA",
                    "score": 0,
                    "parentId": 0
                }
            ],
            "columnCode": "countries",
            "visibilityCriteria": []
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Please read the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to learn how to ask a proper question (with proper formatting).

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.merge

Answer (score 0):

```
var o = JSON.parse(json1)
o.columnHeaders[2].columnValuesLookup = JSON.parse(json2).columnValuesLookup 
JSON.stringify(o)
```